# loop through xslt when we havemultiple elements

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I want to loop through an XML and create records if there are multiple items repeated like below. I should add 4 new record for child in a table for each master like a 123, b 123 etc. My output should be like below

```
a|123
b|123
c|123
d|123

<item>
<master>123</master>
<child1>a</child1>
<child2>b</child2>
<child3>c</child3>
<child4>d</child4>
</item>
```

I have tried below code

```
         <xsl:for-each select="//item">                
            <Row Action="ADD">
              <xsl:value-of select="current()/child1" />|<xsl:value-of  select="current()/master" />
            </Row>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "repeated"? There are no duplicate elements as each child of `item` has a unique name. Also, please add your required output to the question for illustrative purposes. And finally, you don't have 10 elements...

Comment: Please provide some code to demonstrate your efforts to solve this.

Comment: I have update my question

Answer (score 0):

If your context is `item`, you should be able to iterate over each child that is not `master`.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<item>
    <master>123</master>
    <child1>a</child1>
    <child2>b</child2>
    <child3>c</child3>
    <child4>d</child4>
</item>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::master)]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'|',../master,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
a|123
b|123
c|123
d|123
```